# Product URL Magento

Tags: php, magento

**STRUCTURE**

```
Cars (1)
  Honda (2)
    Product: Honda Jazz (1)
  Estates (3)
    Product: Honda Accord - Black (2)
    Product: Honda Accord - Red (3)
  Hatchbacks (4)
    Product: Honda Civic (4)
Volvo (5)…
Vans…
```

**PROBLEM**

If I directly access my product url (http://www.url.com/honda_accord-blcak.html) into browser.

I want to redirect it to this url(http://www.url.com/cars/estates/honda_accord-blcak.html)

Please help.

Comment: You will need to provide custom url rewrite rules, as magento appends category paths in url only if it is accessed from a category page, not for direct access through URL.

Comment: how? can you help me?

Comment: Not exactly, as I've not done that before, but on abstract level, look for some event while product page loads, and in its observer, place your custom code to modify the url by rewriting. Event will be catalog_product_load_after.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>` that will return full url including categories.

Comment: where can i add that code? can you give me the exact file?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

In Admin panel, **system-> Configuration-> Catalog(left side main heading)-> Catalog-> search Engine optimization**. Here you can see the field like **Use categories path for product url's**. Make this field to **YES**. see the below screenshot for the field name.

[image]

Make an **INDEX MANAGEMENT** and **CLEAR CACHE** and reload the product pages.

Comment: yes but it does not solve my problem because when i enter this url (http://www.url.com/honda_accord-blcak.html) to the browser there is no changes to the url.

Comment: did u made index management and cleared your cache after changing the value from "No" to "Yes"??

Comment: yes it works when i click the image of the product it will redirect to the exact url but when i access the url directly to the browser no redirection occurs.

Comment: yes. when you make the option to "YES" both the urls will work. Our site users doesnt know the exact product url and they will visit the product through the categories path only and when u go in this way, the url will be as per ur requirement only. So no need to worry now.

Comment: what i mean is when you access this url (url.com/honda_accord-blcak.html)  it will redirect to this url (http://www.url.com/cars/estates/honda_accord-blcak.html).

Comment: i can't solve the issue. only the product page works but when i try to access directly the url no changes occurs in the url.